# Compare values of a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hello i have the following data frame :

```
df=streets.groupby(['Address','Username'])['Fees'].sum()
df

Address   Username      
street1   acc1         275.39
          acc2         279.60
          acc3         249.96
street2   acc4         10634.11
          acc5         11445.39
          acc5         3832.67
```

I would somehow like to access the values ('Fees') and select only the groups whoose fees difference between them  is less than 50 , in our exampe group with address = street1

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can compute the difference between the max and min per group, if below 50, then all are within 50 of each other:

```
g = df.groupby(level='Address')
s = (g.max()-g.min())
idx = s[s.lt(50)].index

df.loc[idx]
```

output:

```
Address  Username
street1  acc1        275.39
         acc2        279.60
         acc3        249.96
Name: Fee, dtype: float64
```

*NB. what you called `df` is in fact a Series. If it was a DataFrame you would need to do `g = df.groupby(level='Address')['Fee']`*

Used input:

```
df = (pd.Series({('street1', 'acc1'): 275.39,
                 ('street1', 'acc2'): 279.6,
                 ('street1', 'acc3'): 249.96,
                 ('street2', 'acc4'): 10634.11,
                 ('street2', 'acc5'): 3832.67}, name='Fee')
        .rename_axis(['Address', 'Username'])
      )
```

Comment: Thank you so much , that worked for me . I was in generall lookin for the idea of how can i access the elements of a groupby object, so that helped me a lot.